# Set install path for ubuntu-make

Tags: ubuntu-make

I was experimenting with [ubuntu-make](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make) and can not figure out how to specify path for installation so that it does not ask me every time I install something.

This is kind of a workaround:

```bash
echo "\n" | umake ide eclipse
```

Is there a better way to do this?